# Using response data in a controller test

Tags: testing, controller, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the following test in which I use data from a previous request:

```erlang
test "renders user when data is valid", %{conn: conn} do
  conn = post conn, user_path(conn, :create), user: @create_attrs
  assert %{"jwt" => jwt} = json_response(conn, 201)["data"]

  conn = get (conn |> put_req_header("Authorization", "Bearer #{jwt}")), user_path(conn, :show)

  assert %{"id" => _, "email" => "some email", "password_hash" => "some password_hash"} = json_response(conn, 201)["data"]

end
```

However this test fails with:

```erlang
** (Plug.Conn.AlreadySentError) the response was already sent
```

How can I reuse the `conn` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use original `conn` to get desired results from `GET` request (I replaced `conn` with `conn1` for `POST`:

```
test "renders user when data is valid", %{conn: conn} do
  conn1 = post conn, user_path(conn, :create), user: @create_attrs
  assert %{"jwt" => jwt} = json_response(conn1, 201)["data"]

  conn = get (conn |> put_req_header("Authorization", "Bearer #{jwt}")), user_path(conn, :show)

  assert %{"id" => _, "email" => "some email", "password_hash" => "some password_hash"} = json_response(conn, 201)["data"]
end
```